# thousands of records to be inserted into a DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, optimization

My server receives data and should insert or update the existing database tables. My problem is that the amount of data is **huge**, thousands of records are received and writing it one by one can take hours. Is there a way to optimize the writing? I should also say that each write is preceded by a query to check if the record is already in the DB.

Currently, I use a cache with TTL to skip duplicate records. I am also using a semaphore to prevent too many DB write requests at once (can throw a timeout error).

Comment: This depends completely on the database you are using.  Most offer a way to bulk insert/upsert entries.  Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: MySQL, added a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Gather a hundred rows, build a multi-row `INSERT` and execute it.  (10x speedup)
- Put 100 1-row `INSERTs` inside `BEGIN`..`COMMIT`.  (10x speedup)
- Check that you do not have any unused indexes.  (avoids bogging down in the long run)

Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I may have more suggestions.

What do you mean by `duplicate` records?  All columns are the same?  Just some `UNIQUE` column is the same?  There may be techniques to help here.

1000 rows inserted one-by-one should take no more than 10 seconds, even without the above suggestions.  There is something else involved in this process; please elaborate.

Comment: By duplicate records I mean all the fields are equal. Maybe a different DB is more suitable or a non sql?

Comment: With a single column (or a small number of columns) determining equality, a `UNIQUE` index is the way to go.  Do not switch to nosql without first considering how you plan to extract data.